# How do chips with write only functionality that store keys work?

Tags: hardware, hsm

I know there are HSMs that let you enter keys but you cannot read them out. Also the secure element in Android lets you do that too. You can enter keys in them and you can perform operations using those keys but you cannot read them out. How does that functionality work? I mean how do these chips prevent the read-out? What exactly in the chip makes this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The microcontroller (a really tiny computer) in the HSM prevents it - your computer (or whatever device is talking to the HSM) can't directly interact with the memory chip that holds the keys, it has to go through the microcontroller which will allow you to do some operations using the keys (that microcontroller will do the operation and just give you the result), including inserting new keys, but will never give out the keys themselves (unless you find an exploit in the microcontroller's firmware that allows you to execute arbitrary code and dump the keys).

I suggest you read the Wikipedia articles about [smart cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_card), [secure cryptoprocessors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_cryptoprocessor) and [TPMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module).